# How to use the X Window system on chrome-os

Tags: x11, chrome-os

I have a Chromebook and From version 45 or something like that. The X window system was replaced with Googles Proprietary Frecon I was wondering if there is a way to replace Frecon with the X Window System. I do not care if I have to turn off rootfs (I think will be required)